# Loop over pandas column names to create lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops

Here comes an easy one.. I want to create lists from each of the column in my data frame and tried to loop over it.

```
for columnName in grouped.iteritems(): 
    columnName = grouped[columnName]
```

It gives me a `TypeError: '('africa', year` (note africa is one of the columns and year the index). Anybody knows what is going on here?

This is my dataframe

```
continent   africa  antarctica     asia  ...  north america  oceania  south america
year                                     ...                                       
2009           NaN         NaN      1.0  ...            NaN      NaN            NaN
2010          94.0         1.0    306.0  ...           72.0     12.0           21.0
2011          26.0         NaN    171.0  ...           21.0      2.0            4.0
2012         975.0        28.0   5318.0  ...          480.0     58.0          140.0
2013        1627.0        30.0   7363.0  ...          725.0    124.0          335.0
2014        3476.0        41.0   7857.0  ...         1031.0    202.0          520.0
2015        2999.0        43.0  12048.0  ...         1374.0    256.0          668.0
2016        2546.0        55.0  11429.0  ...         1798.0    325.0         3021.0
2017        7486.0       155.0  18467.0  ...         2696.0    640.0         2274.0
2018       10903.0       340.0  22979.0  ...         2921.0    723.0         1702.0
2019        7367.0       194.0  15928.0  ...         1971.0    457.0          993.0

[11 rows x 7 columns]
```

So I would expect to get one list with eleven elements for each column.

Comment: Can you post expected result?

Comment: Done. Let me know if it's not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iteritems returns pairs of column_name, column_data similar to python's dict.items(). If you want to iterate over the column names you can just iterate over grouped like so:

```
result = {}
for column_name in grouped:
    result[column_name] = [*grouped[column_name]]
```

This will leave you with a plain python dict containing plain python lists in `result`. Note that you would get pandas Series instead of lists if you would just do `result[column_name] = grouped[column_name]`.

Comment: Dictionary works as well, and thanks also for the hint about series vs. list.